# Calculating a total using specific array value

Tags: php, loops, oop

***I made some edits so hopefully there is better clarity for what I'm asking***

I'm working on a PHP project where I need to calculate the **Total Price** of an invoice based the totals of individual items.  
Based on our requirements, we are to create an instance variable that holds the class objects, then use a method to loop through the array and calculate a total.
This is what I have so far:
`InvoiceItem` class

```
class InvoiceItem {
    private $itemId;
    private $itemQty;
    private $itemPrice;
    private $itemDescription;
    private $total;

    public function __get($attr) {
        return $this->$attr;
    }
    public function __set($attr, $val) {
        $this->$attr = $val;
    }

    public function calculateItemTotal() {
        // This method will calculate the total by multiplying the quantity times the price.
        $this->total = $this->__get("itemQty") * $this->__get("itemPrice");
    }    
    public function display() {
        // This method will generate a String that contains a one-line value for this object. 
        // It should include all the instance variables and the total for this item.
        $display_format = "ID: %s, Quantity: %s, Price: %s, Description: %s, Total: %s<br />";

        return sprintf($display_format,$this->__get("itemId"),$this->__get("itemQty"),
        $this->__get("itemPrice"),$this->__get("itemDescription"), $this->__get("total"));
    }
}
```

This is what I have (so far) in the class I am trying to do the calculations `Invoice`

```
class Invoice {
    private $items;
    private $invoice_total;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items = array(new InvoiceItem());
    }

    // Magic Method Getters/Setters
    public function __get($attr) {
        return $this->$attr;
    }
    public function __set($attr, $val) {
        $this->$attr = $val;
    }

    public function calculateInvoice() {
        // it's supposed to loop through my array and calculate the invoice total here
    }
    public function displayInvoice() {
        // this is supposed to call the parent 'display()' method to list each InvoiceItem
        // call calculateInvoice() and print the $invoice_total
    }
}
```

The readout at the end should be something like this:
**ID: 1, Quantity: 3, Price: 5, Description: Foo, Total: 15**
**ID: 2, Quantity: 6, Price: 3, Description: Bar, Total: 18**
**Invoice Total: 33**

I am aware that certain things wouldn't the most efficient (off the bat), but I am trying to learn executing it first and then refactoring later on.

Comment: Firstly, an InvoiceItem would "have one" Invoice, and an Invoice would "have many" InvoiceItems, but they wouldn't necessarily be linked and shouldn't inherit or extend

Comment: @RobbieAverill, I'm aware that one normally wouldn't be inheriting in this way.  I am mainly looking to figure out _how_ I can achieve my current ask.  I am planning on doing refactoring/learning once I can learn this first

Comment: Hi @kmancusi - if you stick with the current structure then you should at least change it so that the InvoiceItem extends the Invoice and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The overall structure looks quite OK. You're using composition instead of inheritance for this, which is good.

There are a couple of simple changes which you could to to simplify it further.

- You could slightly change the `Invoice`'s constructor to receive a list of `InvoiceItem` objects. This will make your Invoice class valid from the moment it gets instantiated.

  ```
  public function __construct(array $invoiceItems) {
      $this->loadInvoiceItems($invoiceItems);
  }

  private function loadInvoiceItems(array $invoiceItems){
      $this->items = array_map(function(InvoiceItem $item){
          return $item;
      }, $invoiceItems);
  }
  ```

  This allows your API to look like this, which I'd argue that is clearer and more convenient:

  ```
  $myInvoice = new Invoice([
      new InvoiceItem(1, 2, 2, "4"),
      new InvoiceItem(2, 1, 3, "3"),
      new InvoiceItem(2, 3, 5, "15"),
  ]);
  ```
- For the same price, you could also modify the InvoiceItem's constructor. You don't need to pass in the total, since you can infer it from the quantity and the unit price (unless if there are special rules that prevent this from being true):

  ```
  public function __construct($id, $qty, $price, $description = "") {
      $this->itemId = $id;
      $this->itemQty = $qty;
      $this->itemPrice = $price;
      $this->itemDescription = $description;
      $this->calculateItemTotal();
  }
  ```
- To compute your displayInvoice method, you only need to loop through your items and accumulate the response:

  ```
  public function displayInvoice() {
      $displayItems = $this->fetchAllDisplayItems();
      $displayItems[] = $this->displayInvoiceTotal();

      return implode(PHP_EOL, $displayItems);
  }

  private function fetchAllDisplayItems(){
      return array_map(function(InvoiceItem $item){
          return $item->display();
      }, $this->items);
  }

  private function displayInvoiceTotal(){
      return "Invoice Total: ". $this->calculateTotalInvoice();
  }

  private function calculateTotalInvoice(){
      return array_sum(array_map(function(InvoiceItem $item){
          return $item->getTotal();
      }, $this->items));
  }
  ```
- Another thing I'd strongly suggest you to do, would be to remove the magic methods for getters and setters. Think about what your objects need to be in a valid state and pass it through their constructor. This should get rid of most of the setters. In terms of getters, identify which ones are actually needed and get rid of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback--admittedly, this is definitely above my current level of understanding, but this will be helpful for future work

Comment: Sorry, my response might look a bit dense. Make sure you read it slowly step by step a couple of times. Let me know if you would like me to clarify something or extend further the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong: it was predominately a misunderstanding of *how* to achieve my array

```
class Invoice {
    private $items = array();
    private $invoice_total;

    // Magic Method Getters/Setters
    public function __get($attr) {
        return $this->$attr;
    }
    public function __set($attr, $val) {
        $this->$attr = $val;
    }

    public function calculateInvoice() {
        foreach ($this->__get("items") as $item) {
        $this->invoice_total += $item->itemTotal;
        }
    }
    public function displayInvoice() {
        foreach ($this->__get("items") as $item) {
            $item->calculateItemTotal();    
            echo $item->display();
        }
        $this->calculateInvoice();
        $total_output = "<label for='invoice_total'>" . "Invoice Total: $%s" . "</label>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo sprintf($total_output, $this->__get("invoice_total"));

    }
}
```

This exercise was meant to focus on using values that were hardcoded, so it was more or less a matter of me taking and defining InvoiceItem attributes and storing them into an array properly, whereas I was initially confusing *when* an array was being created